# How to manage long horizontal form

Tags: forms, mobile, responsive-design

I am redesigning a bad design (IMO) dashboard which shows a list of form fields related to each "Team", such as

Title,
First Name,
Last Name

and list goes on. It has total of 18 fields which include a remove button at the end of each row, which can take off each row, if clicked.

On larger desktop, it may seem fine, but on mobile or tablet, it would look really bad. Below is a [image: screen shot] of the fields.

How can i make it easy for user to navigate and still feel that each row in connected on mobile devices or any other then desktop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, in mobile applications single element per row i.e., single column is preferred and 2 column can also be used in some cases.

---

- Group fields which are related to each other if needed use **accordions** or **tabs** or **dropdowns** or **navbar** according to the feasibility to navigate among each of them and try to some of the UI elements as mentioned above so that the user needs not to scroll a lot.

---

- accordion [image: sample of accordion]
  and the rest are standard UI elements which i guess you can easily find out.

Comment: What about on desktop as I need a different way to show the screenshot layout.

Comment: If you are okay with this layout you can implement the same in web but the results i.e., children of them will come on right side of the screen something similar to left nav bar. By this approach you create a similarity in interactionin web and mobile

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at this example for inspiration…
https://material.io/devices/

It allows mobile user to swipe horizontally. Just resize you browser window to see the mobile responsive version.

Comment: I am also looking to make the desktop version more user friendly rather than boring screenshot.